# Archiving Production DB Insert/Update with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a production database and an archive database in a second SQL Server instance.

When I insert or update (NOT DELETE) data in the production database, I need to insert or update the same data in the archive database.

What is the good way for do that?

Thanks

Comment: Write a trigger on archive db ON AFTER INSERT into Prod db

Comment: @Vutukuri What if there are a lot of transactions on his database? Would trigger be the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

If they are in the same db instance, a trigger would be trivial assuming it's not a lot of tables.

If the size of this grows, you'll probably want to look into SQL Server replication.  Microsoft has spent a lot of time and money to do it right.

Comment: I don't want the data deleted from the database production is removed from the archive db, I can do with replication?

Comment: Correct.  You can setup 1 way replication, Production -> Archive.  Changes to Archive data will not effect Production.

Comment: If I delete an entry in the Production DB I need to keep this entry in the Archive. The data of all tables in the production db will be deleted at the beginning of each day... It do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering using triggers for this, then you may want to take into account the load sizes for your production database. If it is very intensive database, consider using some high availability solution such as Replication or Mirroring or Log shipping. Depending on your needs, either of the solution could serve you right. 
Also at the same time, you should consider your "cold" recovery solutions which would need to be changed in accordance to what you implement.

Answer (score 0):

Replication will replicate your deletions as well. However, not deleting the deletions from your archive database may cause problems down the line on unique indexes, where a value is valid in the production database but not valid in the archive database because the values already exist there. If your design means that this is not an issue, then a simple trigger in the production table will do this for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_MyTable_ToArchive ON MyTable FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET ROW_COUNT OFF
    -- First inserts
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ArchiveDB..MyTable ON -- Only if identity column is used
    INSERT INTO ArchiveDB..MyTable(MyTableKey, Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
    SELECT MyTableKey, Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
    FROM inserted i LEFT JOIN deleted d ON i.MyTableKey = d.MyTableKey
    WHERE d.MyTableKey IS NULL
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ArchiveDB..MyTable OFF -- Only if identity column is used

    -- then updates
    UPDATE t SET Col1 = i.col1, col2 = i.col2, col3 = i.col3, ...
    FROM ArchiveDB..MyTable t INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.MyTableKey = i.MyTableKey
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.MyTableKey = d.MyTableKey
END
```

This assumes that your archive database resides on the same server as your production database. If this is not the case, you'll need to create a linked server entry, and then replace `ArchiveDB..MyTable` with `ArchiveServer.ArchiveDB..MyTable`, where `ArchiveServer` is the name of the linked server.

If there is a lot of load on your production database already, however, bear in mind that this will double it. To circumvent this, you can add an update flag field in each of your tables, and run a scheduled task at a time when the database load is at a minimum, like 1am. Your trigger would then set the field to `I` for an insert or `U` for an update in the production database, and the scheduled task would perform then update or insert in the archive database, depending on the value of this field, and then reset the field to `NULL` once it has finished.